# angle annotation text shift above

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I shift the angle annotation text to avoid overlap with the arc?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes,through}
\newcommand{\ann}[4]{
    \draw let \p1=($(#1)-(#2)$),
        \p2=($(#3)-(#2)$),
        \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
        \n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)} 
    in 
    (#2)++(\n1:5pt) arc (\n1:\n2:5pt) node[midway,sloped] {$#4$} ;
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{60}
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at ({cos(\a)},{sin(\a)});
    \coordinate (B) at (-1,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (1,0);
     \draw (O) circle (1);
     \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle
         (A) -- (O)
         ;
     \ann{O}{B}{A}{\theta};
     \ann{O}{A}{B}{\theta};
     \ann{O}{A}{C}{\beta};
     \ann{O}{C}{A}{\beta};

     \foreach \x in {A,B,C,O} {
         \node[circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=1pt,label=\x] at (\x) {};
     }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I use `above`, sometimes it's above and sometimes it's below!
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of readability I would not slope the angles. Rather,

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes,through}
\newcommand{\ann}[4]{
    \draw let \p1=($(#1)-(#2)$),
        \p2=($(#3)-(#2)$),
        \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
        \n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)} 
    in 
    (#2)++(\n1:5pt) arc (\n1:\n2:5pt) (#2)++({(\n1+\n2)/2}:9pt) node {$#4$} ;
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{60}
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at ({cos(\a)},{sin(\a)});
    \coordinate (B) at (-1,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (1,0);
     \draw (O) circle (1);
     \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle
         (A) -- (O)
         ;
     \ann{O}{B}{A}{\theta};
     \ann{O}{A}{B}{\theta};
     \ann{O}{A}{C}{\beta};
     \ann{O}{C}{A}{\beta};

     \foreach \x in {A,B,C,O} {
         \node[circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=1pt,label=\x] at (\x) {};
     }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(From your previous questions I take that you do not want to use the `angles` library, which allows you to annotate angles, too.)

If you want to slope them, you can do that, too. (I do not know if you want to add a rotation angle of 90, which one could do, too.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes,through}
\newcommand{\ann}[4]{
    \draw let \p1=($(#1)-(#2)$),
        \p2=($(#3)-(#2)$),
        \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
        \n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)} 
    in 
    (#2)++(\n1:5pt) arc (\n1:\n2:5pt) (#2)++({(\n1+\n2)/2}:9pt) 
    node[rotate={(\n1+\n2)/2+ifthenelse(cos((\n1+\n2)/2)<0,180,0)}] {$#4$} ;
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{60}
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at ({cos(\a)},{sin(\a)});
    \coordinate (B) at (-1,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (1,0);
     \draw (O) circle (1);
     \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle
         (A) -- (O)
         ;
     \ann{O}{B}{A}{\theta};
     \ann{O}{A}{B}{\theta};
     \ann{O}{A}{C}{\beta};
     \ann{O}{C}{A}{\beta};

     \foreach \x in {A,B,C,O} {
         \node[circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=1pt,label=\x] at (\x) {};
     }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, if add midway in node option, then the shift not happen, not sure why! :-)

Comment: @lucky1928 The `midway` option does work, but it puts the node literally in the middle of the arc. The next step of sophistication would be to use something like `midway,above` (or `below` or `left` or `right`) but then Ti*k*Z would interpret the `above` key depending on the layout. Then you could add `allow upside down`, but it turns out that you know all the data, so it is easier IMHO to do it in the way indicated in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tkzMarkAngle` and `tkzLabelAngle` options from  `tkz-euclide` package to annotate angle.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(60:1){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(-1,0){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(1,0){C}

 \draw (O) circle (1);
 \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle
         (A) -- (O)
         ;

\tkzLabelPoints[above](A,B,C,O)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=2ex](O,B,A)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=2ex](B,A,O)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1ex](O,A,C)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=2ex](A,C,O)

\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.4](O,B,A){$\theta$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.4](B,A,O){$\theta$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.25](O,A,C){$\theta$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.4](A,C,O){$\theta$}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```